# Laravel 5.1 & Cordova Ionic Localhost

Tags: cordova, laravel, laravel-5, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have both `laravel 5.1` running locally in which I have built various api's. I've also created a basic app using `ionic / cordova` - I'm trying to test both the laravel API and Cordova app locally. Is this possible?

Naively I've tried entering the ip address of my locally hosted PC to the http GET request but nothing happened. For example `http://10.111.0.1:8000/API/test`.

Has anyone figured this one out?

Comment: may i know what web server are you using locally? . . you should put your web server to online locally. . if you are using **xampp** .. i think it is automatically set to online and if you are using **wamp** go to the icon below and click **put online**..

Comment: What are you testing your app on? A real device or an emulator? If you are testing on Android you might need to install the whitelist plug-in. If you are testing on iOS you might need this fix: http://blog.ionic.io/ios-9-potential-breaking-change/ If you run the emulator with the -cls options, are there any warnings on the console?

Comment: I'm testing on a real device, I'm also using wamp 2.4.9 - I've clicked the put online using wamp and this seems to allow me to connect via mobile but I can't reach my laravel project.. Should I be able to type the ip and load port 8000 which laravel runs on? If so this currently isn't working :/